# Right exactness of tensor product

Tags: tensor-products

I have often heard that the tensor product is right-exact. However, I've seen two different things and I'm wondering whether both are correct, or only one of them is. The first is that if:

$0\to A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact then

$M\otimes_RA\to M\otimes_R B\to M\otimes_R C\to 0$ is exact.

However the other version is just that if:

$A\to B\to C\to 0$ is exact then

$M\otimes_RA\to M\otimes_R B\to M\otimes_R C\to 0$ is exact.

I would be very grateful if someone could just clear up this doubt of mine because I've given myself a headache over it and can't seem to find the resolution.

Comment: They're equivalent.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan thank you that makes a lot of sense